# What are the differences between theorem, example, def, etc?

Tags: lean, lean4

What are all the differences between these keywords that allow for defining top level variables?

What I have noticed so far is that `theorem`s can't be anonymous — you can write `example : A := B` but not `theorem : A := B`.

Comment: The difference between theorem and def might have to do with VM compilation. At least, that's what lean says if you try to write `theorem thm : ℕ := 0`.

Comment: @user2395649 I'm talking about lean 4 not 3.

Comment: For Lean3, [the lean 3 reference manual](https://leanprover.github.io/reference/declarations.html#basic-declarations) should provide some explanation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An outline of the differences in Lean 4, which you mentioned is the version you are interested in:

- A `def` is the primary way to define a named function / value in Lean. Unless its result type is `Prop` or it is marked `noncomputable`, a `def` will be compiled into Lean's intermediate representation (IR) in preparation for execution by Lean's interpreter and/or for further compilation into C code.

```
def add (x y : Nat) : Nat := x + y -- a simple computation
def one_plus_one_eq_two : 1 + 1 = 2 := rfl -- theorems can be defs too!
```

- A `theorem` is essentially a `noncomputable def`. This means that values defined by a theorem cannot be used in ordinary computation as they will not (and maybe cannot) be compiled down into executable code. Note that Lean erases types (eg., `T : Type u`, `Prop : Type`), propositions (e.g., `1 = 1 : Prop`) and proofs (e.g., `rfl : 1 = 1`) -- all of which are technically noncomputable -- before attempting compilation, which is why they are still safe to use in computable code. Such values are termed *irrelevant* by the Lean compiler IR.

```
theorem foo : Nat := 5
def addFoo (x : Nat) := x + foo 
/-
error: 
failed to compile definition, consider marking it as 'noncomputable' 
because it depends on 'foo', and it does not have executable code
-/
#eval foo -- same error
theorem addFoo' (x : Nat) : Nat := x + foo -- ok
```

- An `example` creates an anonymous `def` that is type checked for correctness and then immediately discarded by Lean. Thus, an `example` has no lasting effect on the environment and cannot be referred to by later declarations. Note that while Lean will end up discarding the code it generates from an `example`, it does still, by default, generate code. Thus, you must mark an `example` `noncomputable` if it uses a noncomputable definition for a (i.e., to define a value that is not erased).

```
example : 1 + 1 = 2 := rfl
example (x y : Nat) : Nat := x + y
example (x : Nat) : Nat := x + foo -- same error as above
noncomputable example (x : Nat) : Nat := x + foo -- ok
```

Note that there are other keywords for defining functions / values (e.g., `axiom`, `opaque`, `abbrev`, etc.) which I have not discussed here as you did not ask about them. Furthermore, given your choice of keywords to compare, it seemed best to focus on the named/anonymous, computable/noncomputable distinctions that separate `def`, `theorem`, and `example`.